# Can you draw over Facebook chat heads on Android?

Tags: android, overlay

I have an app that draws an overlay. However, the Facebook chat heads are always drawn over the top of my overlay. I have tried re-drawing my overlay every second (obviously I wouldn't do this in the final app) but the chat head just stays on top, there isn't even any flicker giving a clue that it's being re-drawn. I would expect the last overlay drawn to win and end up on top so unless Facebook is redrawing at a ridiculous rate what are they doing? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *Any ideas?*  Z-order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the type in the layout params to TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY for Oreo and later and to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT for pre-Oreo.